# LoggerMessage with Serilog (MemoryAllocation)

Tags: c#, .net, logging, serilog

I'm having Memory allocation with LoggerMessage when the ILogger<> provider is Serilog.

This is the results I get using a normal LogInformation() vs the code genereted LogInformation() from LoggerMessage (Provider Serilog):

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen 0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TestSerilog_Logger | 2,844.659 ns | 56.4269 ns | 60.3762 ns | 0.0191 | 600 B |
| TestSerilog_CodeGenLogger | 8,495.991 ns | 168.3194 ns | 281.2240 ns | 0.0458 | 1,464 B |
| TestDefaultProvider_Logger | 73.583 ns | 1.2657 ns | 1.0569 ns | 0.0011 | 32 B |
| TestDefaultProvider_CodeGenLogger | 9.669 ns | 0.1967 ns | 0.1840 ns | - | - |

Code is the same between the two

```
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

```
 [MemoryDiagnoser]
    public class LoggingBenchmark
    {
        private static ILogger<LoggingBenchmark> defaultLoggerWithSerilog;
        private static ApplicationLogger codeGenLoggerSerilog;

        private static ILogger<LoggingBenchmark> defaultLogger;
        private static ApplicationLogger codeGenLogger;

        private static Teste teste;

        [GlobalSetup]
        public void Init()
        {
            teste = new Teste();

            //This is for serilog
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .AddJsonFile(path: "appsettings.json", true, reloadOnChange: true)
                    .Build();

            var sLogger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .CreateLogger();

            var serilogLogger = new SerilogLoggerFactory(sLogger)
                    .CreateLogger<LoggingBenchmark>();

            defaultLoggerWithSerilog = serilogLogger;
            codeGenLoggerSerilog = new ApplicationLogger(serilogLogger);

            //This is for Default logger
            using var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(loggingBuilder => loggingBuilder
                    .SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace));

            var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<LoggingBenchmark>();

            defaultLogger = logger;
            codeGenLogger = new ApplicationLogger(logger);

        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void TestSerilog_Logger()
        {
            defaultLoggerWithSerilog.LogInformation("Teste {t}", teste);
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void TestSerilog_CodeGenLogger()
        {
            codeGenLoggerSerilog.LogInformation(teste, "Teste");
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void TestDefaultProvider_Logger()
        {
            defaultLogger.LogInformation("Teste {t}", teste);
        }

        [Benchmark]
        public void TestDefaultProvider_CodeGenLogger()
        {
            codeGenLogger.LogInformation(teste, "Teste");
        }

    }

    public class Teste
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
```

```
  public void LogInformation<T>(T obj, string message, [CallerMemberName] string callerName = "", [CallerArgumentExpression("obj")] string objName = "") where T : notnull, new()
    {
        LogInformation1CodeGen(_logger, callerName, message, obj,objName);
    }

    [LoggerMessage(
       Level = LogLevel.Information,
       Message = "Information in Method: {MethodName}, with Message {InformationMessage}, {objName}: {obj}")]
    private static partial void LogInformation1CodeGen(ILogger logger, string methodName, string informationMessage, object obj,string objName);
```

Does anyone knows the reason for this?

More Info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/loggermessage?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the code that has been benchmarked.

Comment: @Fildor sorry, maybe now is better?

Comment: Better. Now, Have you had a look into what has actually been auto-created?

Comment: And how did you configure Serilog?

Comment: Off the bat: You are in fact allocating more strings in your generated code. Would be interesting how the generator deals with those.

Comment: And another tip from experience: Also benchmark the case when the loglevel is too low. :D

Comment: @Fildor I have the settings now, i will take a look when im home